# "Disk is read only" when doing backups to an external disk attached to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: time-machine, backup

I have an external USB disk attached to a Raspberry Pi. I've been making Time Machine backups without problems, but today I'm getting an error telling me that the "disk is read-only" and the backup cannot be done.

Previous to that, a verification error appeared giving me two options, use another disk or do a clean backup.

If I attach the disk directly to my Mac, backups are recognized and I can do an incremental backup without issues.

How can I fix this problem so that I can continue doing backups over the network when it's connected to my Raspberry Pi?